# How can i use code completion with fluent interface?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, phpdoc

I wonder how to use autocompletion with inherited class. For exemple i have this kind of code :

```
<?php
    class A {

        /**
         * @return $this
         */
        function a(){
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return $this
         */
        function b(){
            return $this;
        }
    }

    class B extends A{
        function c() {
        }
    }

    $object = new b();
    $object->a()->b()->c();
    ?>
```

When i try to navigate with ctrl+click i can find a and b function but how can i reach c?

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean is called `fluent interface`, not `autocompletion`. You may want to edit your question. :)

Comment: For information, it doesn't work for PHP Storm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the correct [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) style documentation for Eclipse to add autocompletion. In your @return Statement you have to indicate the actual type (name of your class) returned, not the variable:

```
<?php
    class A {

        /**
         * @return A
         */
        function a(){
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return A
         */
        function b(){
            return $this;
        }
    }

    class B extends A{
        /**
         * @return B
         */
        function c() {
        }
    }

    $object = new B();
    $object->a()->b()->c();
?>
```

Now in your example the problem is, that it won't really work with the subclass, because the documentation says that you e.g. for $object->a() return an instance of class A. Therefore autocomplete won't show the methods from class B (you can call them though).

Comment: you're right, i used that syntax in my code and it doesn't work better for the subclass.

Comment: Well PHP is still a dynamic language, so you can only autocomplete that much. You could write @return A | B in your superclass or document them as magic methods in your subclass (haven't tested if it works: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html)

Comment: I'll dig with the phpdoc documentation. Thanks.